# Using jax-ws client methods in Weblogic enviroment

Tags: java, jax-ws, weblogic, nosuchmethoderror

I faced with problem using jax ws client with Weblogic 10.3. I generate webservice stubs and test connection with webservice in simple java project. All works fine. But when I pack this project in jar file and add it to my main project which contains other jars and running on weblogic I get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.home.client.AddressWS.getAddressByRequestAsync(ILjava/lang/String;)Ljavax/xml/ws/Response;
```

This exception was thrown when I tried to call webservice stub`s method.

```
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

private AddressWS service;
private static final String ENDPOINT = "http://endpoint.address.ws.company.org/";
private static final String SERVICE_NAME = "AddressWSImplService";

@Override
public void setSOAPServiceURL(String serviceURL) {
    URL url = createURL(serviceURL);
    QName qName = new QName(ENDPOINT, SERVICE_NAME);
    AddressWSImplService addressWSImplService= new AddressWSImplService(url, qName);
    service = addressWSImplService.getAddressWSImplPort();
}

@Override
public String getAddressById(int id, String param) throws TimeoutException {
    // NoSuchMethodError was thrown here
    final Response<GetAddressById> response = service
            .getAddressByIdAsync(id, param);
    return (String) getValue(new Future<String>() {...});}
```

Any pointers will be helpfull.

Comment: a code snippet would help to analyse your error. how do you call the ws ?

Comment: Tim, thank you for advice. I add code where exception was thrown.